# Powershell batch extract audios from video files command

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell

I have a working bash command to extract all audio tracks of videos in the current folder without re-encoding and put them in a subfolder:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -c:a copy ./audio/"${f%.*}".m4a; done
```

I've been trying to find the equivalent command for PS. How can I do this? When I try the following:

```
ls *.mp4|foreach{
    ffmpeg -i $_ -vn -c:a copy $_.name.replace("mp4", "m4a")
}
```

I get this error on some files with opus audio:

```
[ipod @ 00000000005719c0] Could not find tag for codec opus in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Is there any way to extract audios in whatever format they are on the video file? Mimicking how the bash command works for PS.

Thanks!

Comment: Try instead of `-c:a` to use `-acodec copy`.

Comment: Try: ```ls *.mp4 | foreach{
    ffmpeg -i $_.Name -vn -c:a copy $_.name.replace("mp4", "m4a")
}
```

Comment: Try: `gci *.mp4 | ForEach{ ( 'ffmpeg -i {0} -vn -c:a copy .\audio\{1}.m4a' -f $_.FullName , $_.BaseName ) | Invoke-Expression }`

Comment: Or if ( My being unfamiliar with **ffmpeg** ), quotation marks are need around the paths: `gci *.mp4 | ForEach{( 'ffmpeg -i "{0}" -vn -c:a copy ".\audio\{1}.m4a"' -f $_.FullName , $_.BaseName ) | Invoke-Expression }`

Comment: @KeithMiller your second suggestion leads to the same error as in the question, for some videos it works, for others: `Could not find tag for codec opus in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`

Comment: @harrymc changing that leads to the same error as in the initial question

Comment: @jlo: That's not a **PowerShell** error, so it must be thrown by **ffmpeg**. Have you found any info on that?

Comment: I get that, but weirdly enough in bash I don't get any of the ffmpeg errors. I thought if the syntax was equivalent in PS it should lead to a similar result (on the same machine), but I guess not

Comment: You shouldn/t change the extension like that because `mp4` _could also be part of the file's name (`'Champ4Life.mp4'.Replace("mp4", "m4a") --> Cham4aLife.m4a`) and also, `.Replace()` works case-sensitive. Better use `[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('Champ4Life.mp4', 'm4a')`

Comment: Though you didn't specify, the fact that you referenced my second suggestion (with added quotes) generates the error, I'm guessing ffmpeg wants quoted paths. Do the files that generate errors have any characters with special meaning to **PowerShell**strings (`$`, `[`, `]`for example)? Try this variation of the format string: `'ffmpeg -i ''{0}'' -vn -c:a copy ''.\audio\{1}.m4a'''`